# How do I use where clause query in import excel data to listview

Tags: c#, excel, listview

I'm having a hard time importing Excel to my `ListView`. How do I import Excel data that will match their names in my listview like this?

This is my listview data I want to import that column total in excel that will match to their names in column `Name` just like this:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcrnS.png)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDDcW.png)

This is my code. What query should I use to match all data names in column `Name`?

```
ListViewItem lvis = new ListViewItem();
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string excelName = "Sheet1";
string strConnection = string.Format(connStr);
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter oada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + excelName + "$] Where Name = '" + Name + "';", strConnection);

table.TableName = "TableInfo";
oada.Fill(table);
conn.Close();

// Clear the ListView control
listView1.Items.Clear();

// Display items in the ListView control
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drow = table.Rows[i];

    // Only row that have not been deleted
    if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        // Define the list items
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["Id"].ToString());
        //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Name"].ToString());
        //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Details"].ToString());
        //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Detail2"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Total"].ToString());

        // Add the list items to the ListView
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really, really use a DataGridView.  It will make this much easier (starting with no need to create rows/items).

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for that

```
List<object> listResult = from p in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                          join pm in DataTable2.AsEnumerable()on p.Name equals pm.Name
                          select new { Id= p, Total = pm };
```